# A cube of density

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Never mind the title, some problems are difficult to summarize in words.

I have to demonstrate that for any bounded Lebesgue measurable $E \subseteq \mathbf{R}^d$ there exists a cube $Q \subset \mathbf{R}^d$ of positive sidelength such that $m(E \cap Q) > (1-\epsilon) m(Q)$.

I have to use the fact that $E$ can be approximated by a grid of dyadic cubes of sidelength $2^{-n}$ (it is a grid that becomes finer and finer and thus approximates $E$ well in the area where it intersects it). In other words, for a given $\epsilon>0$ we can find a grid size $2^{-n}$ so small that the difference between the union of the cubes of sidelength $2^{-n}$ that intersect $E$ and the $E$ itself disappears, i.e. $m(E \triangle F) \leq \epsilon$.

I have tried to use all of the possible set-theoretic identities but in the end, I always end up with something in the form of
$$1 - \dfrac{m\left(E \cap Q_n\right)}{m(Q_n)}< \dfrac{\epsilon}{m(Q_n)},$$
where I cannot control the size of $\epsilon$. Any hint would be appreciated.

Many of you probably know of this result as the direct consequence of the Lebesgue differentiation theorem that is used to prove the Steinhaus theorem, yet I am not allowed to use the former result (pedagogical reasons).

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to do the case when $E$ is bounded. Since for any cube $Q$ we have $E \cap Q \subset F = E \cap B(x, R)$ for some $x \in E \cap Q$ and some $R > 0$, one can then replace $E$ by the bounded set $F$.

Suppose that $E$ is bounded and measurable. Let $\varepsilon > 0$. By outer approximation by open set, we can find an open $U \supset E$ such that $m(U \setminus E) < \varepsilon m(U)$. Express $U$ as a countable union of almost disjoint cubes $U = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty Q_n$, and note that $m(U) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty m(Q_n)$ is finite. We claim that $\exists i \geq 1$ such that $m(E \cap Q_i) > (1 - \varepsilon)m(Q_i)$.

To see this, suppose for contradiction that $m(E \cap Q_n) \leq (1 - \varepsilon)m(Q_n)$ for all $n$, then $m(Q_n \setminus E) \geq m(Q_n) - (1 - \varepsilon) m(Q_n) = \varepsilon m(Q_n)$ for all $n$, and thus $m(U \setminus E) = m(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty Q_n \setminus E) \geq \varepsilon \sum_{n=1}^\infty m(Q_n) = \varepsilon m(U)$, a contradiction.

Comment: What is $F$? You never specify this.

Comment: It was a typo, the set inclusion symbol should be an equal sign, corrected.

Comment: Yes, nice, thanks. However it still does not make sense to me. $E$ is already a bounded set. What is the point of renaming it $F$? You also write $E=F$. So this letter $F$ is just an extra letter for something that was already called $E$. What is the point of introducing it?

Comment: $F = E \cap B(x,R)$, not $E$. The claim for the case reduction is justified by showing that we can replace the general $E$ by its’ bounded version $F$. It’d have been better if I have used $E’$ rather than $F$.

Comment: Ok, I see it now. Thanks. I got confused because $E$ was already bounded in the first place (see second line in the question).

Comment: Yes, the argument works for unbounded $E$ as well.